# How to set-up Github Actions for Xamarin apps in windows-latest VM?

Tags: windows, xamarin, sdk, github-actions

In the docs provided here -
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-xamarin-applications#building-xamarinios-apps

The Xamain SDK is installed in the VM is done via this command

```
$VM_ASSETS/select-xamarin-sdk-v2.sh --mono=6.12 --ios=14.10
```

and this is run in the `macos-latest` VM.

How can I do the same thing (tell it to install the Xamarin SDK) in the `windows-latest` VM for Android Apps (I know iOS apps can't be built in the Windows VM)?
If someone tells me how, I'll send a PR to update that doc too.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't build iOS apps in a Windows VM

Comment: OK, but what about Android Apps, they build on Windows. It would still need the Xamarin-SDK/extension installed there for that to work. I've updated the question to clarify exactly what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't unless you also connect that build agent to a macOS machine with all the tools necessary.

Instead, I suggest you use the macOS-11 agents and build your iOS Apps using those. Just like the documentation you link to suggests.

Comment: but what about Android Apps, they build on Windows. It would still need the Xamarin-SDK/extension installed there for that to work. I've updated the question to clarify exactly what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: For Android Apps you can use a windows VM to build those. You don't need the `select-xamarin-sdk` script for that.